# How Can I show Html Math in flutter

Tags: html, flutter, web, math, webview

Here is my Html Text

```
<p>hello</p>
    <div class="mathjax-equation">
        \(x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\)
    </div>
```

I want to show this math view on flutter mobile screen without Webview package. How can I?

Answer (score 1):

Check this package  [flutter_tex](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex)
I also suggest that you use this article in the medium that the creator of the package wrote, it also includes the video [article](https://medium.com/@shahxad/render-maths-equations-in-flutter-with-flutter-tex-23514f9260e4)

Check it all, I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

you can use [math_tex_package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex) for displaying the mathematical equations given that you will reformat how you write the formulas

```html
TeXView(
    child: TeXViewColumn(children: [
      TeXViewInkWell(
        id: "id_0",
        child: TeXViewColumn(children: [
          TeXViewDocument(r"""<h2>Flutter \( \rm\\TeX \)</h2>""",
              style: TeXViewStyle(textAlign: TeXViewTextAlign.Center)),
          TeXViewContainer(
            child: TeXViewImage.network(
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shah-xad/flutter_tex/master/example/assets/flutter_tex_banner.png'),
            style: TeXViewStyle(
              margin: TeXViewMargin.all(10),
              borderRadius: TeXViewBorderRadius.all(20),
            ),
          ),
          TeXViewDocument(r"""<p>                                
                       When \(a \ne 0 \), there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
                       $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$</p>""",
              style: TeXViewStyle.fromCSS(
                  'padding: 15px; color: white; background: green'))
        ]),
      )
    ]),
    style: TeXViewStyle(
      elevation: 10,
      borderRadius: TeXViewBorderRadius.all(25),
      border: TeXViewBorder.all(TeXViewBorderDecoration(
          borderColor: Colors.blue,
          borderStyle: TeXViewBorderStyle.solid,
          borderWidth: 5)),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
   ),
  )
```

and i you need html still, you can use [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)